# math.random function with step option?

Tags: lua

A custom function that will return a random number with a step option available like in the **for** loop.
Example:

```
for i=1,10,**2** do
   print(i)
end
```

Comment: Please, clarify what did you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
function randomWithStep(first, last, stepSize)
    local maxSteps = math.floor((last-first)/step)
    return first + stepSize * math.random(0, maxSteps)
end
```

This gives the same behavior as math.random(first, last) except that the values will be "stepSize" apart. Note that the highest random # may not be "last", depends if (last-first) is a multiple of stepSize.