# How to fix "attempt to concatenate table and string"?

Tags: lua, concatenation, lua-table

I asked a question similar to this the other day, but another bug popped up "attempt to concatenate table and string"

```
local questions={
    EN={
        Q2={"Who is the lead developer of Transformice?","Tigrounette"},
        Q4={"What is Eminem's most viewed song on youtube?","I love the way you lie"},
        Q6={"What is the cubic root of 27?","3"},
        Q8={"What are the first 3 digits of Pi","3.141"},
        Q10={"What is the most populated country?","China"},
        Q12={"What is the plural of the word 'Person'?","People"},
        Q14={"Entomology is the science that studies ...?","Insects"},
        Q16={"Who was the creator of the (bot ran) minigame fight?","Cptp"},
        Q18={"The ozone layer restricts ... radiation","Ultraviolet"},
        Q20={"Filaria is caused by ...","Mosquitos"}
    }
local main = questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)].."%s" -- bug here
local current_answer_en = string.gsub(current_question_en,1,2)
```

Comment: `local question = questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)][1]`

Comment: what about the answer? that's why i want to format it

Comment: `local question, answer = (table.unpack or unpack)(questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)])`

Comment: the `table.unpack` function isn't available in the api of the game i'm executing the code in. any substitute?

Comment: You'd be better off having the Q's be one array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of object is `questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)]`? Say random is 15, what type of object is `questions.EN["Q6"]`? It is a `{"What is the cubic root of 27?","3"}`, which is a table, which Lua doesn't know how to concatenate with a string (`"%s"` in your case). If you want to concatenate with the first item of this table, then

```
local main = questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)][1] .. "%s"
```

Note however that you will need the "random with step" function that I posted in [math.random function with step option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803861/math-random-function-with-step-option/21804299#21804299), otherwise you could get that the table `EN["Q"..something]` is nil (if the random number is an odd number, in the code you posted).

Note sure what you are trying to do with `current_question_en` but if you are trying to extract the question and answer you could do something like this:

```
local QA = questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)] -- this is a table
local question, answer = QA[1], QA[2]
```

The other option is that you build your table like this:

```
local questions={
    EN={
        Q2={q="Who is ..?",   a="Tigrounette"},
        Q4={q="What is ...?", a="I love the way you lie"},
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could use

```
local QA = questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)] -- this is a table
print("The question:", QA.q)
print("The answer:", QA.a)
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with `string.gsub` but it does not take integers as 2nd and 3rd args.

Comment: yeah, i use it. but didn't paste it here not to cause confusion. but how can i add the answer of question X? like for example `{"The ozone layer restricts ... radiation","Ultraviolet"}` how would i get the answer of the question in "`questions.EN["Q"..math.random(1,20)][1]`" i tried using `string.gsub` but it didn't work

Comment: OK, I think I understand, I extended my answer.