# how to get Math.random() with a unit step

Tags: java

I am trying to create a snake game where i have 400x400 pane and the snake moves by 20 at X and Y axis. By doing this i have created a grid that has step of 20 at X and Y axis.

I want to randomly spawn a fruit at the pane but i want the width and height to be in grid so it should spawn at steps of 20 (0, 20, 40, 60 , 80, ... , 400).

I can use Math.random()*400 to get range but i cant give it unit step.

I found this question which is exactly what i asked but the solution is for lua based math.random():
[math.random function with step option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803861/math-random-function-with-step-option)

Here is how i translate the snakes position:

```
if (input.equals(KeyCode.W.toString()) || input.equals(KeyCode.UP.toString()))
    if (snakes.get(0).getY() == 0)
        movement.stop();
    else
        snakes.get(0).setY(snakes.get(0).getY() - 20);
```

*Snakes is an Arraylist of rectangles that expand as it eats food and i want only the head to eat the food
*Food is a circle that spawns at random location

And here is how i check if they come in contact:

```
if (food.getCenterX() == snakes.get(0).getX() && food.getCenterY() == snakes.get(0).getY())
    score++;
setScore();
```

I move my snake over the food but the x and y position don't ever match unless i spawn food myself at the grid (say [20,40] or [60, 200]).

Is there another alternative or random with unit step or some other question that i couldn't find here at stackoverflow that can help me?

Comment: Use java.util.Random to get the next int between 0 and 20. Multiply the value by 20. There you go.

Comment: @JBNizet : not multiply, divide by 20, take the remainder

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' No. An integer between 0 and 20 divided by 20 would always be 0. Read my comment again.

Comment: @JBNizet : misread , sorry , you're right

Comment: @JBNizet your solution works perfectly, Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need integer values you can use `Random.nextInt(int bound)`. This will produce coordinates inside your 20x20 matrix.

```
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.nextInt(20)*20; // values from 0 to 19 inclusively
int y = r.nextInt(20)*20;
```

Comment: That will never return the value 400, as requested in the question.

Comment: @Andreas my understanding was that coordinates go from 0 to 400 so the last "pixel" or piece of the grid will be from 380 to 400. So there will be no cell streching from 400 to 420

Answer (score 2):

If you want a random number out of 0, 20, 40, 60 , 80, ... , 400, then first realize that there are 21 values in that list.

Which means you want a random integer value 0, 1, 2, ..., 20, and then multiply that by 20, to get the step of 20 you want.

Don't use `Math.random()` for this. Sure it's convenient, but mostly is you want `double` values. Instead, use one of the following:

- [`new Random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) - Use in single-threaded code. *Recommended.*
  You should generally only allocate one, then share it throughout your code.
- [`new SplittableRandom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SplittableRandom.html) - Use for parallel computations.
- [`ThreadLocalRandom.current()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) - Use in multi-threaded code, e.g. web servers.

All 3 have a `nextInt(int bound)` which returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive).

*Example*

```
Random rnd = new Random();

// in some loop generating fruits:
int fruitX = rnd.nextInt(21) * 20;
int fruitY = rnd.nextInt(21) * 20;
```